# Timer Job property bag empty

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, central-administration, timer-jobs

I need to set some *properties* in the **timer job property bag**
In the **FeatureActivated** event I use this code to set the property:

```
MyJob job = new MyJob (JobName, webApp);    
// Set my custom property!
job.Properties.Add("test", "test value");    
SPHourlySchedule schedule = new SPHourlySchedule();
schedule.BeginMinute = 0;
schedule.EndMinute = 59;
job.Schedule = schedule;   
job.Update();
```

Then in the **Execute method** of the timer job I use this to get the property:

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
{
    try
    {
        // read my coustom property
        var test = this.Properties["test"].ToString();
```

But I have no properties. (Properties.Count = 0)
I tried to restart the Timer Service several times.

Comment: Have you reset the SharePoint Timer Service? After updating timer job.

Comment: What is the scope of your feature?

Comment: It is Web Application. The timerjob but the bag is empty